# Distinct ellipsoids are not biholomorphic in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am stuck on the following problem:

For each real $p\geq 1$ consider the the set
$$D_p=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2:|z|^{2p}+|w|^2<1\}.$$
Let $p\neq q$, then, there does not exist any biholomorphism between $D_p$ and $D_q$.

I can't even think how to start the proof. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
I found the question from the following article:
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322989

Comment: where did you find this question?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the source.

Comment: It could be not straightforward to prove. I would take a look to M. Range's book: in there you can find the proof of the inequivalence between the unit disk $\{|z|^2+|w|^2<1\}\subset\Bbb C^2$ and the unit polydisk $\{(z,w)\in\Bbb C^2\;:\;|z|<1,|w|<1\}$ (and many other techniques). Maybe you can figure out how to manage this as well.

Comment: Check Lempert's paper "Holomorphic Invariants, Normal Forms, and the Moduli Space of Convex Domains". He gave a complete set of biholomorphic invariants of smooth convex bounded domains in ${\mathbb C}^2$.

Comment: @Joe  Please check out my follow up question

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130918/there-is-no-invertible-linear-mapping-which-maps-complex-ellipsoid-onto-the-unit